# FPS Counter in my game (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, frames

I need to add a working FPS counter in my game (Pong). To make an FPS counter I apparently also need a game loop, I tried making a game loop and FPS counter separately and it seems to be working. However, I am having some problems adding the FPS counter to my Pong game.

This is the code for the game loop/FPS counter:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable{

JFrame frame;
int windowWidth, windowHeight;
Point bollXY;
int screenWidth, screenHeight;
Timer timer;
Image bildPaddel;
Image bildBollen;
int paddelY;
int paddel2Y;
boolean paddelUp, paddelDown;
Random rand;
int score, score2;
boolean bollUp, bollRight, changeDirection;
boolean paused;
int fruktDistansRand;
long time;
int fps, newfps;

private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;



private synchronized void start() {
    if(running)
        return;

    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

private synchronized void stop(){
    if(!running)
        return;

    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Main main = new Main();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(main);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    main.start();
}


@Override
public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks ;
    double delta = 0;
    int updates = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (lastTime - now) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        if(delta >= 1) {
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println("Ticks: " + updates + ", FPS: " + frames);
            updates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}
}
```

I tried adding the FPS counter to the game but it did not work for some reason. If you know how to make a better FPS counter and/or how to add it to the game please help. By the way, I do NOT want the FPS locked at 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer, I'm not finding the cause of your counter's problem. It's fairly complicated for me. But I will give you some code to help get started:

This is a code for an FPS counter:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FPSCounter implements ActionListener {
    private final Timer resetTimer;
    private int current, last;

    public FPSCounter() {
        resetTimer = new Timer(1000, this);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        resetTimer.start();
        current = 0;
        last = -1;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        resetTimer.stop();
        current = -1;
    }

    public synchronized void frame() {
        ++current;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        last = current;
        current = 0;
    }

    public synchronized int get() {
        return last;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final FPSCounter cnt = new FPSCounter();
        cnt.start();
        new Timer(2000, e -> { System.out.println(cnt.get()); }).start();
        while (true)
            cnt.frame();
//        cnt.stop();
    }
}
```

The main method tests that the counter works (every 2 seconds, it prints the number of empty loops per second).

You can use it like so:

1. Add a `private FPSCounter fpscnt;` in your game class.
2. Construct the object in your game's constructor like so: `fpscnt = new FPSCounter();`.
3. Start the counter before the game starts, by calling: `fpscnt.start();`. You can call this inside the game's constructor for example.
4. Now, whenever a frame is painted, you shall call the `frame()` method of the counter. I'm demonstrating up next...
5. Now, whenever you want to get the number of frames per second, you shall call the `get()` method of the counter. I'm demonstrating up next...

So now, inside your game's `paintComponent()` method, the lines printing the number of frames/sec shall look like this:

```
fpscnt.frame(); //Because this is a new frame paint operation.
g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
g.drawString("" + fpscnt.get(), 5, 22); //Paint the FPS.
```

*Note*:
Each value returned by `get()` method is delayed for 1 second. I mean if you see 64 fps, then 64 where the frames in the last (past) second.

So your game's `Main` class should then look like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
    public static class FPSCounter implements ActionListener {
        private final Timer resetTimer;
        private int current, last;

        public FPSCounter() {
            resetTimer = new Timer(1000, this);
        }

        public synchronized void start() {
            resetTimer.start();
            current = 0;
            last = -1;
        }

        public synchronized void stop() {
            resetTimer.stop();
            current = -1;
        }

        public synchronized void frame() {
            ++current;
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            last = current;
            current = 0;
        }

        public synchronized int get() {
            return last;
        }
    }


// Variabler
JFrame frame;
int windowWidth, windowHeight;
Point ballXY;
int screenWidth, screenHeight;
Timer timer;
Image imagePaddle;
Image imageBall;
int paddleY;
int paddle2Y;
boolean paddelUp, paddelDown;
Random rand;
int score, score2;
boolean ballUp, ballRight, changeDirection;
boolean paused;
int DistanceRand;
long time;
int fps, newfps;

private final FPSCounter fpscnt; //added line (step 1).

// Konstruktor
public Main(){
    // Definera variabler
    frame = new JFrame();
    imagePaddle = new ImageIcon("src/images/Player.png").getImage();
    imageBall = new ImageIcon("src/images/Pong.png").getImage();
    ballXY = new Point(673, 352);
    paddleY = 312;
    paddle2Y = 312;
    paddelUp = false;
    rand = new Random();
    score = 0;
    score2 = 0;
    ballUp = false;
    ballRight = false;
    changeDirection = false;
    paused = false;
    DistanceRand = 0;
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    fps = 0;
    newfps = 0;

    // Lyssnare
    frame.addKeyListener(this);

    // Bygga fönstret

    frame.add(this);

    // Obligatoriska egenskaper
    frame.setTitle("Pong");
    frame.setSize(1366, 724);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ballUp = true;
    ballRight = true;
    changeDirection = false;
    ballXY = new Point();

    frame.add(this);

    timer = new Timer(5, this);
    timer.start();

    fpscnt = new FPSCounter(); //added line (step 2).
    fpscnt.start(); //added line (step 3).
}
// Metoder
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(imageBall, ballXY.x, ballXY.y, null);
    g.drawImage(imagePaddle, 50, paddleY, null);
    g.drawImage(imagePaddle, 1300, paddle2Y, null);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 100));
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(score2 + "", 1002, 100);
    g.drawString(score + "", 314, 100);

    if(paused){ 
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 80));
        g.drawString("PAUSED", 510, 370);
        timer.stop();
    }
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= 1000){
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fps = newfps;
        newfps = 0;
    }
    else{
        newfps++;
    }
    fpscnt.frame(); //added line (step 4).
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
    g.drawString("" + fpscnt.get(), 5, 22); //added line (step 5).
}

public void AI(){
    DistanceRand = rand.nextInt(200) + 960;
    if(ballXY.x > DistanceRand && ballXY.x < 1380 && ballRight && paddle2Y > 0 && paddle2Y < 596){
        if(paddle2Y + 50 < ballXY.y){
            paddle2Y = paddle2Y + 3;
        }
        else{
            paddle2Y = paddle2Y - 3;
        }
        if(paddle2Y <= 0){
            paddle2Y = paddle2Y + 3;
        }
        if(paddle2Y >= 596){
            paddle2Y = paddle2Y - 3;
        }
    }
}

public void ifUp(){
    if(ballUp){
        if(changeDirection){
            if(ballXY.y < 0){
                ballUp = false;
            }
            else{
                ballXY.y = ballXY.y - 3;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(ballXY.y < 0){
                ballUp = false;
            }
            else{
                ballXY.y = ballXY.y - 3;
            }
        }
    }

    else{
        if(changeDirection){
            if(ballXY.y > 675){
                ballUp = true;
            }
            else{
                ballXY.y = ballXY.y + 3;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(ballXY.y > 675){
                ballUp = true;
            }
            else{
                ballXY.y = ballXY.y + 3;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void update(){
    if(paddelUp){
        if(paddleY > 0){
            paddleY = paddleY - 3;
        }
    }
    if(paddelDown){
        if(paddleY < 596){
            paddleY = paddleY + 3;
        }
    }

    if(ballRight){

        if(ballXY.x > 1290 && ballXY.x < 1300 && ballXY.y < paddle2Y + 100 && ballXY.y > paddle2Y-20){

            if(!ballUp && ballXY.y < paddle2Y){
                changeDirection = true;
                ballUp = true;
            }
            else if(ballUp && ballXY.y > paddle2Y + 80){
                changeDirection = true;
                ballUp = false;
            }

            ballRight = false;

        }
        else if(ballXY.x > 1600){
            score++;
            ballXY.y = rand.nextInt(690);
            ballXY.x = 678;
        }
        else
            ballXY.x = ballXY.x + 3;


        ifUp();
    }
    else{
        if(ballXY.x > 50 && ballXY.x < 60 &&ballXY.y < paddleY + 100 && ballXY.y > paddleY-20){
            if(!ballUp && ballXY.y < paddleY){
                changeDirection = true;
                ballUp = true;
            }
            else if(ballUp && ballXY.y > paddleY + 80){
                changeDirection = true;
                ballUp = false;
            }
            ballRight = true;
        }
        else if(ballXY.x < -244){
            score2++;
            ballXY.x = 678;
            ballXY.y = rand.nextInt(596);
        }
        else
            ballXY.x = ballXY.x - 3;

        ifUp();
    }
    AI();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    update();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        paddelUp = true;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        paddelDown = true;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        if(paused){
            paused = false;
            timer.start();
        }
        else{
            paused = true;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        paddelUp = false;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        paddelDown = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, it helped a lot. The thing is, I had a timer in the game that didn't let the game run faster than 5ms and now the game ignores that timer and runs REALLY fast. How can I make the game run slower without affecting the fps?

Comment: @J.Doe maybe use [Thread.sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) inside your game's code? (not the painting code)

Comment: Okay, everything is working now except displaying the FPS on the screen. I tried typing what you suggested with g.drawString etc but it didn't work. The frames per second should appear on the screen once every second. Where exactly should I place the code you suggested in your 5 steps?

Comment: @J.Doe the steps are explaining where to put the code for the fps counter. Do you have any questions about the steps? (When I write "game's code" I mean your first class)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having some trouble understanding this last part. I added "Private Main fpscnt;" (My class is called Main) at the start. I added "fpscnt = new Main();" at the start of the constructor. I added "fpscnt.start();" at the bottom of the constructor. I added "fpscnt.frame();", "g.setFont..." and "g.drawString..." in paintComponent. Is there something I'm missing? I'm getting error by running this.

Comment: I did exactly what you showed me but I am getting a really strange error, the window glitches out completely and then the program crashes. When you say "private final FPSCounter fpscnt;" for example, do you mean "private final Main fpscnt;"? If I use "private final FPSCounter fpscnt;" then I'm getting: "FPSCounter cannot be resolved to a type". Are you aware that I'm only using 1 class for this which is the Main class?

Comment: @J.Doe You need both classes Main and FPSCounter. I just putted FPSCounter inside Main now, so now you only need to copy-paste the Main class I posted in my answer. Also, I do *not* mean "private final Main fpscnt;", I mean "private final FPSCounter fpscnt;".

Comment: Alright, the FPS is now showing on the screen and in the console, but the FPS in the console shows about 80 million while the FPS on the screen shows about 200, why is that?

Comment: Okay but still, why are they different? 200 doesn't seem very accurate.

Comment: Well, your code has a Timer object. This timer you set the delay to 5ms (which is the 1/200 of a second). In the action listener of this timer you `repaint()` (which counts as a frame). So there you go: 200 frames per second.

Comment: Okay, any idea how to make it show the correct FPS?

Comment: Sure but the thing is, I want the FPS to go as high as the computer can handle so that you can see a difference on a slower computer for example.

Comment: The Timer object of your class handles this. Reduce its delay to 1 ms (1000fps). Be aware that this is power consuming.

Comment: I don't understand, with the timer at 1 ms the FPS in the console now shows 40 million instead of 80 million and the FPS on the screen is still locked at 200?

Comment: 40 million instead of 80: Maybe your computer is slowed down by another task? Locked 200 FPS: I don't know, but maybe this is related to the event dispatch thread. You see, I'm getting max 60 fps, not 200.

Comment: Try increasing the delay to 10 ms for example, and you shall see 100fps. Increase to 50ms and you shall see 20fps, etc...

Comment: I still don't understand why the FPS on the screen is locked at 200 while the "new Timer(1000, e -> { System.out.println(cnt.get()); }).start();" goes up as high as the computer can handle?

Comment: Becase of the `while (true)` loop.

Comment: How do I bind the "new Timer(1000, e -> { System.out.println(cnt.get()); }).start();" as a variable? It can be printed out but I can't figure out how to make it a variable.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you. Do you mean this(?): `Timer t = new Timer(2000, e -> {System.out.println(cnt.get());}); t.start();`  ??